# Does corda's notary save transaction inputstate or outputState specific information?

Tags: blockchain, corda, notary

Does Notary only save output_index and transaction_id?
Will Notary keep detailed State information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it just stores a map of consumed states (identified by the transaction Id and output index like you mentioned).